# How can I print a textfile on the command prompt in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, printing

How can I print the content of a textfile on the command prompt in Windows?

In Linux I can do this with `less textfile.txt`, `more textfile.txt` or `cat textfile.txt`

What is the command for this in Windows?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`type textfile.txt`
If you want it page-by-page, `more textfile.txt`.

Comment: Or just `more textfile.txt` ... avoids a useless use of `type`

Comment: @Joey: Point taken.

Comment: That was one hell of a lag ;)

Comment: @Joey: Just a year or so. About 31,536,000,000 ms latency.

Comment: @Joey, Why do you say that `type` is useless? It's very useful for piping isn't it?

Comment: @Pacerier, you can redirect input from a file in a shell as well. And most programs dealing with stdin also have a way of dealing with files, e.g. `findstr`/`grep`, etc.

Comment: @Joey, But it's more standard to use only stdin and stdout and ignore the file arguments.

Answer (score 2):

For printing the content of multiple files (e.g. textfile_1.txt, textfile_2.txt) the following, does also works :

```
    type textfile*
```