# How to echo contents of file in a DOS/Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I print a textfile on the command prompt in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/162713/how-can-i-print-a-textfile-on-the-command-prompt-in-windows)

Like in Unix' `cat filename` ...
Can this be done?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You can do this with `type filename` :)

Answer (score 8):

You can `cat` multiple files like this:

```
type file1 file2 file3 2>nul
```

The `2>nul` suppresses the output of the filenames. If a file doesn't end with a carriage return, one will not be added between files.

You can do the same thing like this:

```
copy file1 + file2 + file3 con >nul
```

In this case the `>nul` suppresses output of the file names and the `n file(s) copied` message.

Answer (score 7):

In your command prompt, use the `"type"` command.  You can also pipe it through "more" like in Unix.

- `type filename`

...or...

- `type filename | more`

Comment: Additionally, you can use other redirection operators that are the same as Unix in that you can store output into a file instead of onto the screen (e.g., type filename > filename.out) or take input from a file (e.g., more < filename).  It is important to note that the more advanced uses of these redirection operators that will work in Unix don't always work as expected (if at all) in DOS/Windows environments, but if you keep things simple (and test them) they should always work well for you.